# Why more than one select input doesn't work? - Selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page where the user has to choose options that will be in dropdowns (select tag). I'm using selectize to add features on that select tag's, but when the user uses the button to add more select inputs, the first one stops working, but the second one works perfectly. You can see in:

```js
var numberofSelects = 0;
var maxSelects = 9; // 10 Inputs

function addInput() {
  if (numberofSelects < maxSelects) {
    numberofSelects++;
    var newSelect =
      'Input ' + numberofSelects + ' - <select id="model-select' + numberofSelects + '" value="Selecione">' +
      '<optgroup label="Fluorescente">' +
      '<option value="0">Fluorescente 20w</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Fluorescente 40w</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Fluorescente HO 40w</option>' +
      '</optgroup>' +
      '<option value="3">Metalica 400w</option>' +
      '</select><br>';
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += newSelect
    $('#model-select' + numberofSelects).selectize(); // Selectize the new select input
  } else {
    window.alert("Limit reached")
  }
}

$('#model-select0').selectize();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/selectize.js"></script>
<link href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="main">
  <button onclick="addInput();">Add Input</button>
  <br> Input 0 -
  <select id="model-select0" value="Selecione">
    <optgroup label="Fluorescente">
      <option value="0">Fluorescente 20w</option>
      <option value="1">Fluorescente 40w</option>
      <option value="2">Fluorescente HO 40w</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="3">Metalica 400w</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```

Only the last "select" works. I don't understand why.
I have had this problem for days. 
I will be grateful for the help.

Sorry for the English.

Comment: Which first one are you talkiing about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += newSelect`. On the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) it says:

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

So in first removing all of the child elements and then re-adding them, the elements are new elements and lose all of the JavaScript event handlers.

A simple change, to using jQuery's [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), fixes your problem.

```js
var numberofSelects = 0;
var maxSelects = 9; // 10 Inputs

function addInput() {
  if (numberofSelects < maxSelects) {
    numberofSelects++;
    var newSelect =
      'Input ' + numberofSelects + ' - <select id="model-select' + numberofSelects + '" value="Selecione">' +
      '<optgroup label="Fluorescente">' +
      '<option value="0">Fluorescente 20w</option>' +
      '<option value="1">Fluorescente 40w</option>' +
      '<option value="2">Fluorescente HO 40w</option>' +
      '</optgroup>' +
      '<option value="3">Metalica 400w</option>' +
      '</select><br>';
    
    $('#main').append(newSelect);
    
    $('#model-select' + numberofSelects).selectize(); // Selectize the new select input
  } else {
    window.alert("Limit reached")
  }
}

$('#model-select0').selectize();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/selectize.js"></script>
<link href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="main">
  <button onclick="addInput();">Add Input</button>
  <br> Input 0 -
  <select id="model-select0" value="Selecione">
    <optgroup label="Fluorescente">
      <option value="0">Fluorescente 20w</option>
      <option value="1">Fluorescente 40w</option>
      <option value="2">Fluorescente HO 40w</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="3">Metalica 400w</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch for the answer, it's worked very well! Now i will only need to discover how to remove lines and reorganize them haha

Comment: No problem, read over the jQuery API method names and get an idea of what they do, that should help you in future. Good luck. http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 1):

Change your code that *selectize* your `select` element:

```
$('#model-select0').selectize();
```

to this:

```
$('select[id*="model-select"]').selectize();
```

As `$('#model-select0')` only selects your single `select` element whereas you want to *selectize* all your `select` tags.

**Another solution**(*but it will selectize all the `select` elements on your webpage*)

```
$('select').selectize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!